# Лишнее сообщение после остановки цикла =(

Tags: javascript

Почему после того, как я пишу в prompt слово **стоп**, которое останавливает цикл,
то выходит сообщение:

> **Для проверки введите слово "Да" или "Da", следующий запрос на проверку через 1,5 секунды**

Как это пофиксить? Нужно чтобы после cлова **стоп**(остановки цикла) не выходило это сообщение.

```js
let obj = {}; // Пустой объект

Object.defineProperties(obj, { // Добавить 5 свойств в объект

name:{value: 'Domik', writable: true,}, // 1-свойство(data-properties или свойства-данные)
age: {value: 28, writable: true,},      // 2-свойство
setName: {value: '', writable: true,},  // 3-свойство
setAge:{value: '', writable: true,},    // 4-свойство

getter2: { // 5-свойство(Property-accessor или свойство-аксессор)
get() {
this.setName = prompt('Ваше имя?');        // записать данные из prompt в свойство 'setName'
this.setAge = +prompt('Ваш возраст?');     // записать данные из prompt в свойство 'setAge'
                                           // Вывести все 4 свойства  
alert(`Имя директора ${this.name}        
Возраст директора: ${this.age} 
Ваше имя: ${this.setName}
Ваш возраст: ${this.setAge} `);
},
},
})


obj.getter2;     // Вызвать 5-свойство(свойство-аксессор) из обьекта
let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj);

let go = setTimeout(function opa() { // Функция цикл, которая каждые 1,5 секунды срабатывает

let check = prompt('Проверить содержимое объекта?');
let LowerCase = ''; // Начальная пустая переменная нужна, чтобы было куда записать данные из prompt

if (check == null) {
alert(`Вы отменили проверку,
следующий запрос на проверку через 1,5 секунды`);
} 

else{
LowerCase = check.toLowerCase();
if (LowerCase == 'da' || LowerCase == 'да') {
alert(JSON.stringify(descriptor, null, 2));
} 


else {                                             // Как это пофиксить? Почему после остановки 
                                                   // цикла выходит это сообщение?
alert(`Для проверки введите слово "Да" или "Da",
следующий запрос на проверку через 1,5 секунды`);
}
}



if (LowerCase == 'стоп' || LowerCase == 'stop') {  // После остановки цикла выходит лишнее сообщение сверху
clearTimeout(go);
alert('Вы сломали цикл, запросов больше не будет');
return;
}

go = setTimeout(opa, 1500); 
}, 1500)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так работает. Обратите внимание на то куда я переместил блок с проверкой на стоп, он должен быть внутри альтернативной проверки отмены запроса, а не просто посреди всего.

```
        let obj = {}; // Пустой объект

        Object.defineProperties(obj, { // Добавить 5 свойств в объект

            name: {value: 'Domik', writable: true,}, // 1-свойство(data-properties или свойства-данные)
            age: {value: 28, writable: true,},      // 2-свойство
            setName: {value: '', writable: true,},  // 3-свойство
            setAge: {value: '', writable: true,},    // 4-свойство

            getter2: { // 5-свойство(Property-accessor или свойство-аксессор)
                get() {
                    this.setName = prompt('Ваше имя?');        // записать данные из prompt в свойство 'setName'
                    this.setAge = +prompt('Ваш возраст?');     // записать данные из prompt в свойство 'setAge'
                                                               // Вывести все 4 свойства
                    alert(`Имя директора ${this.name}        
Возраст директора: ${this.age} 
Ваше имя: ${this.setName}
Ваш возраст: ${this.setAge} `);
                },
            },
        })


        obj.getter2;     // Вызвать 5-свойство(свойство-аксессор) из обьекта
        let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj);

        let go = setTimeout(function opa() { // Функция цикл, которая каждые 1,5 секунды срабатывает

            let check = prompt('Проверить содержимое объекта?');
            let LowerCase = ''; // Начальная пустая переменная нужна, чтобы было куда записать данные из prompt

            if (check == null) {
                alert(`Вы отменили проверку,
следующий запрос на проверку через 1,5 секунды`);
            } else {
                LowerCase = check.toLowerCase();
                if (LowerCase == 'da' || LowerCase == 'да') {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(descriptor, null, 2));
                } else if (LowerCase == 'стоп' || LowerCase == 'stop') {  // После остановки цикла выходит лишнее сообщение сверху
                    clearTimeout(go);
                    alert('Вы сломали цикл, запросов больше не будет');
                    return;
                } else {                                             // Как это пофиксить? Почему после остановки
                    // цикла выходит это сообщение?
                    alert(`Для проверки введите слово "Да" или "Da",
следующий запрос на проверку через 1,5 секунды`);
                }
            }

            go = setTimeout(opa, 1500);
        }, 1500)
```